# UICollectionView cell for item at index path based on variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to register a second cell based on a variable from core data call hasImage. When the variable is present I want the collection view to use the media cell, when it is not I want it to use the regular cell.

originally I used the following for the cell at index path:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath :
    IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as!
    ShareCell

    let friend = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Friend

    cell.cell = friend.lastMessage

    return cell

}
```

The code above works perfectly fine.

Below is my attempt at creating the new logic.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath :
    IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    var cellprop: Cell? {
        didSet{

        if cellprop?.hasImage == false {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as!
            ShareCell

            let friend = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Friend

            cell.cell = friend.lastMessage

            return cell
        }
        }
    }

}
```

The error I get is unexpected non-void return value in void function.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

ShareCell works perfectly fine and it's subclassed as BaseCell which is defined as asides from that it's a normal collectionViewCell

```
class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    fatalError("init(coder:)has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews(){
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
}
```

Comment: what is `cell.cell` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your question is confusing!

I'm assuming that you want to choose media cell or regular on the basis of whether last message has an image or not.
If that's the case, then here is the solution:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath :
    IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    let friend = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Friend
    if friend.lastMessage.hasImage {
        let mediaCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: mediaCellId, for: indexPath) as!
    MediaCell
        mediaCell.message = friend.lastMessage
        return mediaCell
    }
    else {
        let regularCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: regularCellId, for: indexPath) as!
    RegularCell
        regularCell.message = friend.lastMessage
        return regularCell
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't produce any errors. However, the cells in the collection view are either ALL returned as regular cells or media cells.

Answer (score 0):

You have described setter for `cellprop` variable, but it is never called in your code. And your `return` statement is only in that dead scope

Answer (score 0):

You need return cell within cellForItemAt indexPath.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath :
    IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        var cellprop: Cell? 
        if cellprop.hasImage == false {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as!
            ShareCell

            let friend = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Friend

            cell.cell = friend.lastMessage

            return cell
        }
       else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId2, for: indexPath) as!
            RegulerCell
            return cell
        }


}
```

Comment: I can't access the member hasImage and it's definitely there.

Comment: The NSManaged Object is called Cell and one of the properties is .hasImage but I can't access it. It says the instance member can't be used on type Cell.

Comment: This will crash because you are using the same reuse identifier to return different cell types.

Comment: I think it will only for guidance that is based on assuming you have to change the identifier because you want to use two cell in a single table

Comment: I still can't return cell, the error is now cannot convert return expression of type ShareCell to return type Cell

Comment: is ShareCell is child of UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: I don't understand about your classes and the type, so if u can share the code I can resolve this or you can update your question with more information. :)

Comment: I updated the question. If you would like me to send you the code I can it's a lot though.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is because you are trying to return cell from within a didSet method. You can't do that, because didSet is a void function.

You shouldn't really be using didSet in this context anyhow.

You should create two prototype cells in the storyboard with unique reuse identifiers.

In cellForItemAt, you should create one of these cells using dequeueReusableCell, set properties on the cell, and return it. It's a basic if-else statement, nothing more.

The if condition needs to check hasImage, which means you need access to the Core Data entity corresponding to the cell you are creating.

Comment: I'm not using storyboards and I'm having issues accessing the core data entity.